# Cannot transfer/delete files to ~/Library/Application Scripts/ in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, applescript, xctest

I'm trying to copy a set of AppleScript files to ~/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.test.MyApp-Runner/

```
let destinationURL = try! fileManager.url(
        for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.applicationScriptsDirectory,
        in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask,
        appropriateFor:nil,
        create: true)
...
```

When I try to execute this line (if item exists in destination)

```
fileManager.replaceItem(at: destinationURL, withItemAt: theFileURL, backupItemName: nil, resultingItemURL: nil)
```

I get an error of

```
The file "AppleScript.scpt" couldn't be saved in the folder "com.apple.test.MyApp-Runner"
```

And when I execute this (if item does not exist in destination)

```
fileManager.copyItem(at: theFileURL, to: destinationURL)
```

I get an error of

```
setting security information: Operation not permitted
```

Is FileManager permitted to write into the ~/Library/Application Scripts/?
Is there a permission setting I have to apply?

edit:
Also, executing

```
fileManager.removeItem(at: theFileURLInApplicationScript)
```

throws error code 513 "...couldn't be removed because you don't have permission to access it."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmacos%5D+sandbox

Comment: Isn’t this just standard sandboxing?

Comment: My application is sandboxed. So with sandboxing, there's no way to transfer file to Application Script folder?

Comment: Isn’t that what’s answered by the search link you’ve already been given?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [NSUserAppleScriptTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserapplescripttask)

> If the application is sandboxed, then the script must be in the `FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.applicationScriptsDirectory` folder. A sandboxed application may read from, **but not write to**, this folder.

Comment: You *can* write the the folder if you have a security-scoped bookmark, just like any other directory: https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/sandbox-scripting/